# How to pass a method with parameters as sfWidgetFormPropelChoice(Symfony) option?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I building a Form with widgets. One of them is a Multichoices Form, that i build using **sfWidgetFormPropelChoice**. Into my customForm.class.php i have this:

**customForm.class.php:**

```
class customForm extends BaseCustomForm{
  public function configure(){
   ....
   $this->setWidgets(array(
    ...
    'myMultiChoice'=>new sfWidgetFormPropelChoice(array('model'=>'custom', 'method'=>'getLotsOfThings'));
    ...
  ));
 }
}
```

The option `'method'` is getting a method `'getLotsOfThings'` which dont have any parameters. How can i pass instead this method with parameters?

I try `'method'=>'getLotsOfThings('.$value.')'` but this dont work!

Answer (score 1):

You should have to use the `criteria` option instead ([see the code](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/plugins/sfPropelPlugin/lib/widget/sfWidgetFormPropelChoice.class.php#L28)) which give you the ability to have a complex query to retrieve items.

For example:

```
$c= new Criteria();
$c->add(CountryPeer::idcontinent, 1);

$this->widgetSchema['departement_id'] = new sfWidgetFormPropelChoice(array(
  'model'     => 'Country', 
  'add_empty' => true, 
  'criteria'  => $c
));
```

Give the criteria as an option to the Form when you create it.